# Getting details with People picker with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-infopath

I created a custom list and in my list I have a People picker.

I can quickly type someone's name in AD and they appear.

However when I need to export to Excel,  I get some basic info

```
EmployeeName    Item    sites/Lists/Sign Up
```

I would like to export

```
Name, Phone, Title, Division
```

I am not sure where to begin. I do have InfoPath 2013 installed on my PC (but we aren't allowed to use C# to do code level things. I think VBA is ok)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The person field is a complex object in SharePoint and it does not come across to Excel with all these properties when you simply export the list.

As an alternative to Export, you could use Power Query to access the list. With Power Query, the person field can be expanded to show all these properties.

Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transform.

Create a new query to the SharePoint site, select the list, select the fields you want to show in the table.

[image]

Then click the Expand button for the person field and select the properties you want to show.

[image]

Save the query into a worksheet. When the data in SharePoint changes, you can refresh the query with Data > Refresh All.

Comment: The only data I am able to get is the name of the employee.